# type for specific object values

Tags: typescript

I have object with route paths

```
const adminRoutes = {
  users: "/admin/users",
  organizations: "/admin/organizations",
}
```

I need to specify the type of `adminRoutes` values in array

```
interface IAdminRoutesList {
  path: TAdminRoutesValues;
  element: JSX.Element;
}
const adminList: IAdminRoutesList[] = [
  { path: adminRoutes.users, element: <Users /> },
];
```

The only way to do this that I found is

```
type TAdminRoutesKeys = keyof typeof adminRoutes;
type TAdminRoutesValues = (typeof adminRoutes)[TAdminRoutesKeys];
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result more elegantly, in one line of code?

Comment: Inline it? `type TAdminRoutesValues = (typeof adminRoutes)[keyof typeof adminRoutes];`

Comment: it works! `type TAdminRoutesValues = (typeof adminRoutes)[keyof typeof adminRoutes];`